# New Ubuntu User, Touchpad not working; I know what to do but not how to do it

Tags: touchpad, laptop

[This article](https://alpha-labs.net/2015/08/lenovo-s21e-linux-and-the-touchpad/) describes the exact problem I'm having. I have the same laptop, same issue. Unfortunately, I'm not knowledgeable enough with Linux yet -- I want to learn more but I really just need to get the touchpad to work as soon as possible. I hate to ask anyone to hold my hand through this but could someone give me directions for how to implement the solutions in the article? I would greatly appreciate it, thanks!

```
Output of xinput:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA2B27:00 06CB:2956                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft 3-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)    id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

uname -a

Linux PC-Lenovo-S21e-20 3.19.0-31-generic #36~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 10:21:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I can't get the solutions in this article either. But I program linux touchpad drivers ))). Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: And I do not actually see ANY solution for the touchpad there. Also specify your Ubuntu version and kernel version.